# trying to copy forms from one Access db to another and get "The database has been placed in a state...."

Tags: ms-access-2010

This was working this morning and I had no problem.   I've got two versions of the same database, and am trying to copy some updated objects (forms mostly) from one to the other.  This was working this morning.  Don't know what changed.

I am the only person in the database.  I closed down all code windows.  I tried while in design mode on a form, and not in design mode.  Both talk to a split backend.  One has a couple of local copies of tables that are linked on the source database.

Not sure what to check.  I compacted and repaired the destination database too, that was giving the error, just in case some gremlins were hiding out.

I tried closing the source database, but it said it would empty the clipboard if I did that, and I would lose the object I was trying to copy.  WORKED THIS MORNING, on another version of the database.

Any pointers?   I checked several of the other posts with "database has been placed in a state" in their text, but nothing seemed to be on the money.

Comment: Can you restore all 3 dbs from backups, compact and repair first, then try again?  Try 1-2 forms at a time, saving new copies after each successful step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it had to do with trying to move from a 2002-2003 database to a more modern one.  Others have had similar problems from this same situation.